# tamil font could not be registered in reactPDF

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

In my react app, I have to create PDF I am using ReactPDF library. I tried to register tamil font. But It shows junk characters only and text wraping also not working

this is the font link

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+Tamil&display=swap

Most of tamil fonts are in unicode, I tried lot more fonts also,

```
Font.register({
  family: "FamilyName",
  src: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/notosanstamil/NotoSansTamil-Black.pdf",
  fontStyle: "normal",
  fontWeight: "normal",
  fonts: [
    {
      src: "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+Tamil&display=swap",
    },
  ],
});
```

and code to show is

```
                         <View style={[s.tR, s.notes]}>
                            <View>
                              <Text>Note:</Text>
                              <Text debug={true}>
                                {"\n"}
                                {test.desc}
                              </Text>
                            </View>
                          </View>
```

```
        test: {
          test_id: 8,
          test_name: "HbA1C",
          rate: 0,
          desc: "சர்க்கரை நோய் அல்லாத ஒருவருக்கு HbA1C அளவு 5.7% சதவிகிதத்திற்கு குறைவாகவே இருக்கும்\n\nHbA1C-ன் அளவு 5.7லிருந்து 6.4 சதவிகிதம் இருப்பின், அவர்கள் ஆரம்ப நிலை நீரிழிவினை நெருங்கிக் கொண்டிருப்பவர். அதாவது, அவர்களுக்கு பின்னாளில் சர்க்கரை நோயின் தாக்கம் வரும் வாய்ப்பு உள்ளது.\nHbA1C-ன் அளவு, 6.5 சதவிகிதம் அல்லது அதற்கு மேல் சென்றால் அவர்கள் சர்க்கரை நோய்க்கு உட்பட்டு இருக்கிறார் என்று பொருள்.\nHbA1C-ன் அளவு, 8 சதவிகிதத்திற்கு மேல் இருப்பின், சர்க்கரை  நோய் கட்டுப்பாட்டில் இல்லை என்று பொருள். மேலும்,வருங்காலத்தில் சர்க்கரை நோய் சிக்கல்களுக்கு உட்படும் நிலை ஏற்படும்.\nHbA1C-ன் அளவு, 7 சதவிகிதம் அதற்கு கீழிருக்கும் போது அவர்களுக்கு மருத்துவர், பொதுவான நீரிழிவு சிகிச்சை திட்ட முறைனை பின்பற்றுவார்.\nHbA1C-ன் அளவு, 7 சதவிகிதத்திற்கு மேலிருக்கும் போது, மருத்துவர், சிகிச்சை முறை தீர்மானத்தில் மாற்றம் ஏற்படுத்துவார்.",
          createdAt: null,
          updatedAt: "2023-05-06T09:02:44.942Z",
          deletedAt: null,
        },
```